# Code Challenge in python not working correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Ok so I don't know what am I doing wrong, I hope you people can enlighten me.

This is the challenge:

> 1. Convert a zero based number into a binary form using the following rules: a) flag "0" means that the following sequence of zeros should
>      be appended to a binary string. b) flag "00" means that the following
>      sequence of zeroes should be transformed into a sequence of ones and
>      appended to a binary string.
>
> 00 0 0 00 00 0 --> 1001
>
> 2- Convert the obtained binary string into an integer.
>
> 1001 --> 9
>
> Input sample:
>
> Your program should accept as its first argument a path to a filename.
>   Each line of input contains a string with zero based number. E.g.
>
> 00 0 0 00 00 0
>
> 00 0
>
> 00 0 0 000 00 0000000 0 000
>
> 0 000000000 00 00
>
> Output sample:
>
> For each line from input, print an integer representation of a zero
>   based number. E.g.
>
> 9
>
> 1
>
> 9208
>
> 3

This is my code:

```
import sys

def StringToBinary(flag,zero):
    val=str()
    if flag=="0":
        for i in zero:
            val+="0"
    elif flag=="00":
        for i in zero:
            val+="1" 
    return (val)

binary=str()
num=1
flag=""
zero=""
test_cases = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
for test in test_cases:
    for i in test.strip().split(" "):
        if num%2!=0:
            flag=i
            num+=1
        elif num%2==0:
            zero=i
            binary+=StringToBinary(flag,zero)
    print(int(binary, 2))
    binary=""


test_cases.close()
```

And my output is always 0, and I don't understand why if I'm assigning the value "1" in the function when it is needed.

Anyone can figure out what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Uh.... if `0 == 0` and `00 == 1` how does `00 0 0 00 00 0 == 1001`?  Shouldn't it be `00 0 0 00 00 0 == 011001`?

Comment: also beware... SO doesn't exactly like homework questions.  Finally, you "test cases" file should probably be included.

Comment: I think this is code eval not homework

Comment: When I run your program with your test data, the output I get is `127`, `7`, `1048575`, `16383`. Not the right answers, but not always `0`. So… presumably the code you posted here has already fixed the problem you're asking about?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham fair enough

Comment: Meanwhile, what have you done to try to debug this? You understand what each line is supposed to do, but nobody else does. For example, if you can verify that you're calling `StringToBinary` in the right places, and with the right values, then we only have to look inside that function. And you can verify that by just using a debugger breakpoint, or adding a `print` statement to the function, but nobody else can verify it because they don't know what the right places and values are.

Comment: @KronoS read more carefully. 00 means that the *next* block is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't increment num in the case where it is even. Also, you don't reset it at the start of each line.

Rather than doing that explicitly, it's better to use `enumerate` to keep your counter:

```
for num, i in enunerate(test.strip().split(" ")):
```

Comment: Thanks my friend! I was just missing the num increment

Comment: @FutoFarai: That is a bug in your code, but… it doesn't cause the problem you described in the question, it causes a very different problem. (Which makes sense, given that your code doesn't do what you described in the question in the first place…)

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "00 0 0 00 00 0".split()
translate = lambda (flag,zeros):zeros if flag=="0" else zeros.replace("0","1")
decoded_bin = map(translate,zip(s[::2],s[1::2]))
print int("".join(decoded_bin),2)
```

is probably how I would solve this ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in a functional style:

```
tok = "00 0 0 000 00 0000000 0 000".split()
i = int(''.join( map( lambda x: len(x[1]) * '1' if x[0] == '00' else x[1],
                 zip(tok[0::2], tok[1::2]))),
        base=2)
print i == 9208
```

**1st step: tokenize**

```
>>> tok = "00 0 0 000 00 0000000 0 000".split()
>>> print tok
['00', '0', '0', '000', '00', '0000000', '0', '000']
```

**2nd step: build tuples of flag and value**

```
>>> x = zip(tok[0::2], tok[1::2])
>>> print x
[('00', '0'), ('0', '000'), ('00', '0000000'), ('0', '000')]
```

**3rd step: conditionally covert input to a sequence of '0's or '1's**

```
>>> x = map( lambda x: len(x[1]) * '1' if x[0] == '00' else x[1], x )
>>> print x
['1', '000', '1111111', '000']
```

**4st step: join the list to a string**

```
>>> x = ''.join(x)
>>> print x
'10001111111000'
```

**5th step: convert the string to integer with base 2**

```
>>> int(x, base=2)
9208
```

**voilà**

Comment: Please explain your solution in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This one does the math instead of string manipulation; should take less memory and be a bit faster.

```
# assumes Python 3

def pairs(iterable):
    # "abcdef" => ("a","b"), ("c","d"), ("e","f")
    it = iter(iterable)
    return zip(it, it)

def decode(s):
    value = 0
    for flag,zeros in pairs(s.split()):
        shift = len(zeros)
        if flag == "0":
            value <<= shift
        else:
            value = ((value + 1) << shift) - 1
    return value

with open(sys.argv[1]) as inf:
    for line in inf:
        print(decode(line))
```